# Why do negative inputs not work in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

Nothing shows up if scanner input is negative.
If i enter -11 then 10, -10 and -1 should be the output.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String replay = "replay";
        while(replay.equals("replay"))
        {
        System.out.println("The numbers that add to be ___(number1)___ that multiply to be ___(number2)___ are...");
        System.out.println("Enter number1:");
        int n1 = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number2:");
        int n2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Computing...");
        for(double f2 = -1000; f2 <= n1; f2++)
        {
            for(double f1 = -1000; f1 <= n1; f1++)
            {
                if(f1*f2 == n2 && f1+f2 == n1)
                {
                    System.out.println(f1 + " and " + f2);
                }
            }
        }    
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter replay if you would like to compute again");
        replay = scan.nextLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Even though my loop variables are negative.

Comment: you should probably make f1 and f2 ints rather than mixing doubles and ints in your calculations.  you can get rounding issues with doubles which can cause problems such as 1.00000000000001 != 1 . I'm not saying this is necessarily your problem here though

Comment: Did iterating till 1000 solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your scanner can take negative numbers, it is functioning perfectly. You do not get the expected output because your loop ends at n1 being -11, so the loops don't get to the point where (f1*f2 == n2 && f1+f2 == n1) is true. If you iterate, lets say from -1000 till 1000, you will get the desired output.

This code:

```
`import java.util.Scanner;

public class NegativeScanner{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String replay = "replay";
        while(replay.equals("replay"))
        {
        System.out.println("The numbers that add to be ___(number1)___ that multiply to be ___(number2)___ are...");
        System.out.println("Enter number1:");
        int n1 = scan.nextInt(); //-11
        System.out.println("Enter number2:");
        int n2 = scan.nextInt(); // 10

        System.out.println("Computing...");
        for(double f2 = -1000; f2 <= 1000; f2++){ //-1000-től -11-ig

            for(double f1 = -1000; f1 <= 1000; f1++){ //-1000-től -11-ig

                if(f1*f2 == n2 && f1+f2 == n1)
                {
                    System.out.println(f1 + " and " + f2);
                }
            }
        }    
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter replay if you would like to compute again");
        replay = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

yields this output:

`The numbers that add to be ___(number1)___ that multiply to be ___(number2)___ are...
Enter number1:
-11
Enter number2:
10
Computing...
-1.0 and -10.0
-10.0 and -1.0
Enter replay if you would like to compute again`

Answer (score 0):

values of f1 and f2 are less than -11. Maybe for the boundary of loop will be better java.lang.Math.max(n1,n2)